# How to enable autocomplete for custom imported modules in atom editor for python environment?

Tags: python-3.x, ide, atom-editor

import numpy

numpy.(tab) (a window pop ups with all the functions of numpy )

import custom_made_module

custom_made_module.(tab) (no list pop ups )

**how to get autocompletion for custom made modules in python for atom IDE ?**

Answer (score 1):

Check [Kite Plugin](https://kite.com), it uses AI to improve your coding experience.

Comment: auto completion is not working, do I have to include my project in any path or make it root folder like in pycharm ? Please help I am stuck

Comment: Actually i use Sublime Text, and it works fine to me. Check [this](https://atom.io/packages/kite) and make sure your Atom autocomplete config is enable.

Comment: Thanks for your time people, I switched to pycharm less of a headache now everythings works great too